# Use SQL Server view in NEW Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, cordova, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am new to Azure App Service.

I've created a view in Azure database to get data across several tables. Now I want to use the data from this view in my Cordova App using the Azure Mobile Service (MobileService.GetTable...). I found several articles in the web that describe how to do that in Classic Azure Portal. But I need a solution for the NEW Azure App Service with Node.js Backend.

What is the syntax to return data from a view as an Azure table?

```
var table = module.exports = require('azure-mobile-apps').table();
table.read(function (context) {
// *** Need code to return data from sql view ***
//return context.execute();
});
```

And it would be great to use a parameter to filter data in the view before returning.

Thanks,
Uwe

Answer (score 3):

You are pretty much right there.  You need to just create a table controller to access the view.  Ensure you have the system columns defined (version, updatedAt, createdAt, deleted and id).  Also, ensure the right thing happens when you update the view (e.g. with an INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) as that will tell you what needs to be done with the controller (for example, if you can't insert/update/delete, then make it read-only).

Reference blog post for you: https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/15/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-8-table-controller-basics/

Comment: Hi Adrian. Thanks for your quick answer and your great blog. I added the system columns to my view (version, updatedAt, createdAt, deleted and id). But I am not able to figure out how to get data from a sql view inside a table controller.

Could you please provide a sample of a table controller that returns data from a database view instead of a database table?

Thanks again,
Uwe

Answer (score 0):

Things can be so easy sometimes ;-)

All I need to do is to write the following lines to my table controller:

```
var table = require('azure-mobile-apps').table();
table.databaseTableName = 'ViewName';
module.exports = table;
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey, any chance you can elaborate on how you solved this problem? I am trying to accomplish the same thing. I created a view "MyView" and an EasyTable "ViewController" -- I'm not sure what code goes where, though. (Like the code in this post -- does this go in app.js or "ViewController.js")?

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue but fixed it now, am using a .Net backend thou.
1. Log into azure portal and select the database you want to create the view in Then select the query Editor in the left pane.
2. Use the sql to create the query.
3.Create  a table in the asp.net backend that matches your fields in your view.
4.Go to your asp.net backend and create a custom Api and write the following codes:

```
public class HelloCustomController : ApiController
{
    MobileServiceContext context;
    public HelloCustomController()
    {
        context = new MobileServiceContext();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<List<vwUser>> Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var users = context.Database.SqlQuery<vwUser>("Select * from 
             dbo.vwUser);
            return await users.ToListAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return new List<vwUser>()
            {
                new vwUser
                {
                    UserName=ex.Message
                }
            };
        }
     }
```

4.You edit my codes to select from your view.
5. Create a similar class in your mobile app that matches what u created in your backend.
5. You can then access your view by calling it in  your mobile app with the following codes:

```
var users= await client.InvokeApiAsync<vwUser>("HelloCustom",HttpMethod.Get,null);
```

Thanks Guys. This is my fisrt answer to this beautiful community that carried me from day 1 of programming till now that am a bit conversant.