# How can I access a database view using Aure App Service tables?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services, windows-10-universal

I'm using Azure App Service to create a Windows 10 app. I have a view that I'd like to access in the same way you access the EasyTables. Using the old Mobile Services, I had it working. With the new SDK, the old way doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Example: Create an EasyTable called "ViewController", a database view named "MyView" and whenever a call is made to "ViewController", it acts as though it's the view.

This is using a node.js backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible - we use views for mapping from the older Mobile Services data schema to the newer Mobile Apps schema. I haven't actually tried it on a hosted service, but if you create the table in Easy Tables, delete the table using SSMS and create a view with the same name, it should just work.

Keep in mind that your view must return the appropriate set of reserved columns - createdAt, updatedAt, version and deleted (if soft delete is turned on). The primary key must be called id. We are looking at allowing customisable names for these columns but it's currently not possible.

Comment: That's the method I used for the old service; it doesn't work anymore. Although I didn't try also adding those columns -- do I just select them from one of the joined tables?

Here's someone that solved my issue but I can't figure out how to do it for myself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36699626/use-sql-server-view-in-new-azure-app-service

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot! It didn't work for me originally because I didn't have those columns in the view.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to only select the authenticated user's data from the view? On a normal table, I put this in the node.js script: // Ensure that only records for the authenticated user are retrieved
table.read(function (context) {
    context.query.where({ userId: context.user.id });
    return context.execute();
});

Comment: Provided that the userId column is returned from the view, this approach should still work. For info, we'll be releasing a new version of Mobile Apps next week that includes a new data filter for creating tables with per-user data.

Comment: userID isn't part of any of my tables, it's built into Azure using an Authentication Service (Microsoft Account, in my case). Not sure how I can access that from a view. Should I just create a new topic? :P

Comment: There is a long answer and a short answer - the short answer is that we'll be releasing a new version next week that makes this really easy. Feel free to open a new topic for the long answer!

Answer (score 0):

Check out my blog post on the topic: https://shellmonger.com/2016/05/11/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-19-asp-net-table-controllers/