# How to join two tables in azure mobile apps in android?

Tags: android, sql, azure

I can query an= table in android but how do I have join table A with table B that has a foreign key?

Comment: I answered this question on another thread, you can check it out.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49072418/6224552

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, there are two ways for implementing your needs.

1. Creating a `View` for joining table `A` with table `B` on Azure SQL Database, then you can query data from the view in Android using Azure Mobile Apps.
2. Creating a custom api to execute custom SQL statements at the backend of Azure Mobile App, then call the custom api from the android client. Please refer to the subsection `How to: Execute custom SQL statements` in the tutorial section [`Custom APIs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk#a-namecustomapia-custom-apis) for backend and the tutorial section [`How to: Call a custom API`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-android-how-to-use-client-library#a-namecustom-apiahow-to-call-a-custom-api) for Android client.